# Map list inside class to a list inside another class using Automapper

Tags: c#

I am trying to map property ProjectLocation inside class Project with property Project_Locations inside class Project_Master

```
public class Project
{
   public int ProjectId { get; set; }
   public string ProjectCode { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<ProjectLocation> ProjectLocation { get; set; }
}

public partial class Project_Master
{
  public int ProjectId { get; set; }
  public string ProjectCode { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Project_Locations> Project_Locations { get; set; }
}

public partial class Project_Locations
{
    public int ProjectLocationId { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual Project_Master Project_Master { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectLocation
{
    public int ProjectLocationId { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

My mapper configuration

```
CreateMap<Models.Project.Project, Dal.Repository.Project_Master>();
CreateMap<Models.Project.ProjectLocation, Dal.Repository.Project_Locations>();
```

Instance of class

```
Models.Project.Project project = new Models.Project.Project();
project.ProjectId = 1;
project.ProjectLocation = new List<Models.Project.ProjectLocation>();
project.ProjectLocation.Add(new Models.Project.ProjectLocation() { LocationId = 2, ProjectId = 1 });
```

Mapping code

```
var proj = mapper.Map<Dal.Repository.Project_Master>(project);
```

Comment: And whats the problem ?

Comment: What happens? Is there some error message?

Comment: It would help to add a tag for automapper to get better focus on the question.

Comment: There is no error message. But the data is not getting mapped to the other object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added following to the configuration file

```
CreateMap<Models.Project.Project, Dal.Repository.Project_Master>().ForMember(dest => dest.Project_Locations, opt => opt.MapFrom(src=> src.ProjectLocation));
```